# Android : AppWidget Grid View icons get cleared and Widget stops responding click

Tags: android, widget

I have created a Simple home screen widget which shows current time and date with predefined app icon in grid view. I am updating date and time using alarm manager on OnReceive event. When I click on Clock it open configuration screen.

My problem is that when I run some other application mostly games, the application icons disappears from the widget and the widget stops responding on click. but OnReceive method works properly and updating the clock.

I cant understand why this is happening. please help me.

**OnReceive Code**

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        // // Get shared prefs
        myPref = new SharedPref(context);
        try {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "OnRecive Called : " + intent.getAction());

            if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Clock update");
                // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then
                // // call the shared // clock update method.
                ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
                for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // mWidgetId = getWidgetId(intent);

    }
```

**OnUpdate Code**

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;

        myPref = new SharedPref(context);
        mWidgetId = appWidgetIds[N - 1];
        addWidget_Database_Detail(context);

        // insert Add Button
        // insertAddAppButton(context);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updating Example Widgets.");
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
        // provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Configuration_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, randomGenerator.nextInt(100), intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.linearLayout_Time, pendingIntent);

            setUpAppGrid(context, appWidgetManager, mWidgetId);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
            // widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            // Update The clock label using a shared method
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
```